# Counting outcomes for three dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Given are three 6 sided dice, which we throw at the same time.

The outcome of the throw is given by the triple $(x,y,z)$. I want to know how many combinations have at least one of the dice with a $2$ showing up.

How can I count them without writing down every possible combination $\{(2,1,1),(2,2,1),..\}$? Any well known formula for this kind of counting problems?

Comment: Consider complementary probabilities. You are looking for the probability that at least one of the dice will show a $2$. The complementary probability is that no die shows a $2$. This probability is much easier to calculate. The probability you want is $100\%$ minus the probability that no die rolls a $2$. (This is an either or. Either no die rolls a $2$, or at least one die rolls a $2$. There are no other possible outcomes, which is why we can apply the Law of Total Probability).

Answer (score 1):

There are $6 \times 6 \times 6 = 216$ possible outcomes. The number of outcomes where $2$ does not appear at all is $5 \times 5 \times 5 = 125$.

The number of outcomes where $2$ appears at least once is $216 - 125 = 91$.